# Flutter: I'm getting the type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' when I am using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hello guys I am using a stream builder to get data from fireStore collection to display some posts but I am getting an error saying **type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'** and the value of the snapshot is null

this is the post model that I have

```
class Post {


 final String id;
  final String description;
  final String validUntil;
  final String availableFor;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String owner;



Post({
    required this.id,
    required this.description,
    required this.validUntil,
    required this.availableFor,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.owner,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'description': description,
        'validUntil': validUntil,
        'availableFor': availableFor,
        'imageUrl': imageUrl,
        'owner': owner,
      };

  static Post fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        id: json['id'],
        description: json['description'],
        validUntil: json['validUntil'],
        availableFor: json['availableFor'],
        imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
        owner: json['owner'],
      );
}
```

and this is the Stream

```
Stream<List<Post>> readPosts() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('posts')
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) =>
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
```

and this is the StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
                stream: readPosts(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      print(snapshot.error.toString());
                      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                    } else {
                      final posts = snapshot.data;
                      return Column(
                        children: posts!.map(buildPost).toList(),
                      );
                    }
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                })
```

I would really appreciate it if you can help me solve this problem

Comment: At what line exactly does Flutter report the error. Like go through the logs where the error is reported, locate what line in the file and then indicate above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some data as a null value. To fix it you can default any null value to something else with the [null coalescing operator `??`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators).

The code's going to look like this:

```dart
class Post {
  final String id;
  final String description;
  final String validUntil;
  final String availableFor;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String owner;

  Post({
    required this.id,
    required this.description,
    required this.validUntil,
    required this.availableFor,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.owner,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'description': description,
        'validUntil': validUntil,
        'availableFor': availableFor,
        'imageUrl': imageUrl,
        'owner': owner,
      };

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'] ?? '',
        description = json['description'] ?? '',
        validUntil = json['validUntil'] ?? '',
        availableFor = json['availableFor'] ?? '',
        imageUrl = json['imageUrl'] ?? '',
        owner = json['owner'] ?? '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you the issue was that I had a document which doesn't have the same fields like the others

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of the values in the Post is null in Firebase, such as description or imageUrl. Print the doc to try troubleshooting the problem like this:

```
Stream<List<Post>> readPosts() =>
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      print(snapshot);
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        print(doc.data());
        return Post.fromJson(doc.data());
      }).toList();
    });
```

Comment: I used the code that you provided, and it seems that all the data are not null in the doc this is the output that I got

{owner: GGsxq4eriSpN7PEzhtC7, availableFor: All, imageUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/capstone-742c1.appspot.com/o/files%2FLvST5guB487uNHiDs8sg%2Fpost%20picture?alt=media&token=8e50f3fa-b903-4844-bbf2-5a3e1f87f88a, description: Test Description , validUntil: 11/1/2022, id: 20kU6eLMVEG1SHaywBKI}

Comment: Is that output for the first or second print?

Comment: it is for the second print
the output for the first print is:
Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

Answer (score 0):

As i seen in your code you have created model which `not-null` type `model` create `nullable` model for that you can use https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/ website to `generate model`.

Don't forgot to do this
[image]